# Is there a list of possible value for SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY

Tags: oracle-spatial

When the geometry is valid return `'TRUE'` but when is invalid return an error code, You can google each one, but I want to have a system user-friendly where when I found a wrong geometry already said what is the problem so user proceed to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps https://community.oracle.com/thread/675210 helps you.